# Why does a small rounding error for np in pbinom() generate a relatively large error in the calculated p?

Tags: r

I have a function to calculate probabilities for a binomial distribution. The user could enter a sample probability. Let's say they had 25 out of 35. They calculate a probability as 0.7143 and enter that into the function.

Since I am using pbinom() I'll multiply that probability by the sample size to get the quantile. Look at the differences when I reproduce the math here, first with a calculated quantile and second with the actual count.

```
> 2*pbinom(.7143*35,35,.5,lower.tail = FALSE)+dbinom(.7143*35,35,.5)
[1] 0.005988121
Warning message:
In dbinom(0.7143 * 35, 35, 0.5) : non-integer x = 25.000500

> 2*pbinom(25,35,.5,lower.tail = FALSE)+dbinom(25,35,.5)
[1] 0.01133098
```

A difference of that amount in the tail could lead to a different conclusion.

Here is an example away from the tails with 18 out of 35:

```
> 2*pbinom(.5143*35,35,.5,lower.tail = FALSE)+dbinom(.5143*35,35,.5)
[1] 0.7358788
Warning message:
In dbinom(0.5143 * 35, 35, 0.5) : non-integer x = 18.000500
> 2*pbinom(18,35,.5,lower.tail = FALSE)+dbinom(18,35,.5)
[1] 0.8679394
```

That is a difference of 13% in the p-value.

I understand why the warning message appears and I can easily fix it by rounding, but why does a tiny error of 0.0005 in the quantile affect the calculated p-value so much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a comment in the documentation that directly addresses this:

```
If an element of x is not integer, the result of dbinom is zero, with a warning.
```

So it's not numerical error, per se, it's that if you give `dbinom` a non-integer it will always return 0, with a warning. So yes, the solution is to always check your inputs to ensure they are integers.